# Make 3 list items without repeating the code

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This is my first list Activity.

I need to make another list Activity in first item and another list Activity in any item.

In the second list Activity I need to do these all without repeating the code and where I can change the data of each list

```
Toolbar mToolbar;
ListView mListView;

String[] countryNames = {"Australia", "Brazil", "China", "France", "Germany", "India", "Ireland", "Italy"
        , "Mexico", "Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "US","Ahmed"};
int[] countryFlags = {R.drawable.flag_australia,
        R.drawable.flag_brazil,
        R.drawable.flag_china,
        R.drawable.flag_france,
        R.drawable.flag_germany,
        R.drawable.flag_india,
        R.drawable.flag_ireland,
        R.drawable.flag_italy,
        R.drawable.flag_maxico,
        R.drawable.flag_poland,
        R.drawable.flag_russia,
        R.drawable.flag_spain,
        R.drawable.flag_us,
        R.drawable.ana};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, countryNames, countryFlags);
    mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("countryName", countryNames[i]);
            mIntent.putExtra("countryFlag", countryFlags[i]);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

and this is my code for the Adpater

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] names;
int[] flags;
Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] countryNames, int[] countryFlags) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.listview_item);
    this.names = countryNames;
    this.flags = countryFlags;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.mFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mViewHolder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    mViewHolder.mFlag.setImageResource(flags[position]);
    mViewHolder.mName.setText(names[position]);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mFlag;
    TextView mName;
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to "edit" a list "across activities", try a database

Comment: @cricket_007 think OP wants a reusable activity with code for handling the list with different data.

Comment: could you help in this?

Comment: @t0mm13b Perhaps. All I'm saying is that a SQLite table can "move" the two arrays in the one activity into a database that is shared over the whole app

Comment: *in second list activity i need to do these all without repeating the code and where i can change the data of each list*

Comment: i'm using firebase and the main problem i don't know how to make the 2 other list

Comment: What do you mean you are using Firebase? Your question has no Firebase code

Comment: the first activity in log in i used firebase for it 
forget what i said and tell me what to do cause i'm new android

Comment: It's fine that you are new, but I don't understand the question or see what you have at least tried to solve your problem. You seem to think we're just going to write some code for you based on some vague description of what you're wanting. In other words, assuming you could get it all "working", how do you want to "use it"?

Comment: You might want to use an ExpandableListView

Comment: how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second Activity listed here is a detail Activity...
And you only have two items to detail (name and flag), not a list...

So, maybe the following isn't what you want

---

You mention using Firebase for logging in. You can store your lists in Firebase and query for them, so that is one thing.

---

Whether or not you have data in Firebase, I would still recommend you create a class which can be serialized. (Though research `Parcelable` as a better alternative).

If you need to have "3 items" like you say, this is where you do it.

```
public class Country implements Serializable {
    String name;
    int flag;

    public Country(String name, int flag) {
        this.name = name;
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

Store a list somewhere you can access from different places.

Add more parameters, as necessary.

```
public List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new Country("Australia", R.drawable.flag_australia),
    new Country("Brazil", R.drawable.flag_brazil)
));
```

You may be tempted to make this `static`, but try not to.

---

Fix up your adapter to accept that class instead of two (or more) arrays.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Country> countries) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_item, countries);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    // TODO: Update getView too
```

---

And then you should be able to use this to start the other Activity

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, countries);
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Country country = myAdapter.getItem(i);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("country", country);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
});
```

---

And in the next Activity, you can use

```
Country country = null; 
Intent extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    country = (Country) extras.getSerializable("country");
}
if (country != null) {
    nameTextView.setText(country.name);
    flagImageView.setImageResource(country.flag);
}
```

Comment: in 3rd step there is an error in 3rd line which is countryNames and for 4th and 5th shloud i create new class or put them in MyAdapter class &sorry for distribution ..................

Comment: Yeah, code untested, thanks for catching that. You should create a `Country.java` file with that class.

Comment: i made it before i told you and the error is still exist

Comment: i changed countrNames to countries he tells me 'Can't resolve method super'.

Comment: Should work... `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)` Don't change the name only. You need a `List<Country>`.

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: i think this full code i need but what can i write in the main activity bro?

Comment: The code block containing `mListView.setAdapter` should already be part of the MainActivity that I copied from your question.